# what is line sequential buffer length in informatica?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I need explanation for below questions.

what is line sequential buffer length in informatica?
how integration service handles when allocated buffer is full?

Answer (score 1):

Line sequential buffer length in informatica is a property of session which specifies the accepted length of bytes from an individual record of a flat file source. The default size is 1024 as can be seen in the attached screenshot.

[image]

To improve the performance of a session generally the size is decreased.
When the allocated buffer is full, the integration service stops the execution of the session and logs the error message in the session logs.